# Input in Null terminating character array and getting its length

Tags: arrays, c, null, string-length, null-terminated

I hava a question.....I have a character array char command[30]. When I use it for input like if I entered !! on console the after input strlength function must give me length of array equals to 2 as it does not count null character. But It is giving me 3 as length of array. Why is it happening.

```
    char command[30];
    fgets(command,30,stdin);
    printf("%zu",strlen(command));
```

Comment: Have you looked at the actual values stored in your array? Either with a debugger or printing them to console?

Comment: Yes I have printed character by character...but it is giving me same string as I input to it...like !!

Comment: That is not possible, because `fgets`, as stated in the documentation, will store a newline character if it encounters it. So you cannot have printed the string - and especially the integral values of the characters stored in it - and gotten only 2 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably including the `newline` character - the `Enter` key.

Try this to remove the `newine` character, then strlen should be as you expect:

`command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: Is it due to fgets.....or this problem will be same in scanf

Comment: Why `strcspn` instead of `strchr`? You are looking for a single character

Comment: @IslamicPalace What do you mean "due to fgets"?  The behavior of `fgets` is to write the newline if there is space.  With scanf, whether or not the newline is written will depend on the format string.

Answer (score 0):

fgets adds the newline character '\n' to the characters you type in, adding an extra character to the length of the string. So if you type !! and hit "Enter", the characters '!', '!', and '\n', get stored in your command[] array. Thus, the strlen() function returns the length of your string as 3, instead of 2. To fix this, just subtract 1 from the result of the strlen() function, and write a null zero ('\0') to the position where the the '\n' was.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char command[30];
    
    printf("Enter text: ");

    fgets(command, 30, stdin);

    int length = strlen(command);

    command[length - 1] = '\0';

    printf("String length is %lu\n", strlen(command));

    return 0;
}
```